# EnvironmentCredential authentication error while trying to run timer-triggered functions when deployed

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a timer triggered function that runs func locally but when published I get the error

```
[Error] Executed 'AppServiceSupervisorFunc' (Failed, Id=7xxxx-4f53-aee2-25241792cab8, Duration=6576ms)EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information
```

first few lines of code where the error might be generating this error are

```
    var monitoringClient = await GetMonitorClientAsync();
        ArmClient client = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
        string resourceGroupName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ResourceGroupName");

  private async Task<MonitorManagementClient> GetMonitorClientAsync()
    {
        var serviceCreds = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync("xxxthcare.onmicrosoft.com", "8xxx-xxx-ad2b-8f608daf80db", "RPt8Q~JxxxUjbKxxx0TFaUH");
        var monitorClient = new MonitorManagementClient(serviceCreds);
        monitorClient.SubscriptionId = "xxx77-427b-8cdd-6fd9343040ab";
        return monitorClient;
    }
```

any suggestions?

**Update**
I enabled app insights and it looks like error is being generated at groupList.GetAsync call.

> AppServiceSupervisorFunc DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credential

```
            var SubscriptionResourceId = new ResourceIdentifier(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SubscriptionResourceId"));

        SubscriptionResource sub = client.GetSubscriptionResource(SubscriptionResourceId);
        var groupList = sub.GetResourceGroups();
        var group = await groupList.GetAsync(resourceGroupName);
```

[image]

**update2**
when i used

```
  ArmClient client = new ArmClient(new AzureCliCredential());
```

i get Azure CLI not installed error in Azfuction's console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The reason the  `DefaultAzureCredential`  is not working is because the`DefaultAzureCredential`  uses credentials stored in the cache when you login in you Microsoft account, azure cli etc. But here in case of the function app there is no credentials in the cache.
- So, to make the `DefaultAzureCredential` work you will have to Register an app in azure AD and client id, tenant id and client credentials from that app to use `DefaultAzureCredential`.
- First register your app in azure ad for that in portal locate `azure ad` and go under the `App Registration` and click on `New Registration`.

[image]

- Fill the subsequent form and then click on Register.

[image]

- Now locate your recently registered app in the list and click on it.

[image]

- Then copy the `Clientid` and `Tenant id` from that app.

[image]

- Now generate a client secret by going under the `Certificates & secret` tab and click on `New client secret`

[image]

- fill the subsequent form and click on add after that you will see the new generated client secret in the list.

[image]

- Copy new generated client secret

[image]

- Now you will have to add all the copied `Clientid`,`tenantid`,`client secret` in the app setting of the function which is under `Configuration` tab, just click on new app settings.

[image]

Use the following names:

`AZURE_CLIENT_ID`

`AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`

`AZURE_TENANT_ID`

Now add the previously copied strings(clientid,tenantid,etc) in the app settings.

[image]

- Now `DefaultAzureCredential` can work and provide auth tokens.'
- Also `AzureCliCredential` requires azure cli where you will have to login first. That's why it is giving you the error.